# Show that two matrices are similar when they have the same characteristic polynomial and a cyclic vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, characteristic-polynomial, similar-matrices

I need to show that if $A$ and $B$ have a cyclic vector and have equal characteristic polynomial, then they are similar.

Here I know that given $T: V \rightarrow V$ with $n=\operatorname{dim} V,$ a $T$ -cyclic vector $v \in V$ satisfies $B=\left(v, T(v), \ldots, T^{n-1}(v)\right)$ is an ordered basis of $V$, and $[T]_{B}=L_{\Delta_{T}}=L_{\psi_{T}}$, where $L_{f}$ is the companion matrix defined by the polynomial $f$.
But I'm not seeing how I can use this information to prove what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all of the pieces, you just need to put them together.

$A$ and $B$ have a cyclic vector and have common characteristic polynomial $f$. Let $v$ denote an $A$-cyclic vector, and let $w$ denote a $B$-cyclic vector. Let $\mathcal A = (v,Av,\dots,A^{n-1}v)$, and let $\mathcal B = (w,Bw,\dots,B^{n-1}w)$. We note that
$$
[A]_{\mathcal A} = [B]_{\mathcal B} = L_f.
$$
In other words, $A$ is similar to $L_f$ and $B$ is similar to $L_f$. Because matrix similarity is an equivalence relation, this means that $A$ is similar to $B$.